# A Batch file to read a file and replace a string with a new one

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

I want to create a batch file to read every line of a file in a loop and replace a string with another one. Following is my code snippet:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (myfile) do (
  set str=%%i
  set str=%str: %oldstring% = %newstring%%
echo %str% >> newfile
)
```

This results in a newfile with 'Echo is off' as many lines as there are in myfile. Seems like str variable holds no value at all when assigned to %%i. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out this small script:

```
@echo off
set val=50
echo %val%
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do (
    set val=%%i
    echo %val%
)
echo %val%
pause>nul
```

The output is:

```
50
50
1
```

Not what you expected, right?

That's because in a `for` loop, variables aren't updated until the loop has finished. To combat this, you can use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, and replace the percent signs (`%`) with an exclamation mark (`!`):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set val=50
echo %val%
for /l %%i in (1,1,1,) do (
    set val=%%i
    echo !val!
)
echo %val%
pause>nul
```

The output:

```
50
1
1
```

The reason the `str` variable holds no value (during the `for` loop) is because it hasn't been set beforehand.

So, with these quick modifications, your script will work...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (myfile) do (
    set str=%%i
    set str=!str: %oldstring% = %newstring%!
    echo !str! >> newfile
)
```

By the way, this snippet is assuming that `oldstring` and `newstring` won't be set within the forloop, otherwise things will get messy.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks a trillion!! I'm absolutely new in batch programming. I've seen 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' before but dint know its function. Hence never used it. Thank you for the explanation. And yes, oldstring & newstring were set outside the loop and my code works fine now! Thanks again..:)

Comment: @user2147904 Did it answer your question, if it did, click accept. If it only helped, upvote.

Comment: Hi Prof Pickle, I had another question. I think you cannot give space after str:. Now, suppose oldstring is a variable assigned (and changed) inside the for loop. Then we have to use set str=!str:!oldstring!=%newstring%!. But it doesnt work as it when it encounters 2nd !, it terminates the purpose. What is the solution? Please help.

Comment: Try set str=%str:!oldstring!=!newstring!% i'm on my phone so I can't test it

Comment: Can you avoid setting `%oldstring%` in the `for` loop?

Comment: Actually I need to read all the text files from a folder and then replace a certain type of string with another in each of them. So, the oldstring keeps changing with every file. Thats y I have to keep it in the for loop. Following is the code snippet: for /r %%g in (*.txt) do (
set filename=%%~nxg
echo !filename!
for /F "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%i in ('findstr "volumelabel" !filename!') do (
set oldstring=%%i
)
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (!filename!) do (
set str=%%a
set str=%str:!oldstring!=%newstring%%
echo !str!>>new!filename!
)
)

Comment: I guess the only thing to do now is to post another question.

Comment: What folder? It doesnt create any folder. It prints only 'oldstring' (literally) in every line of the new files when set str=!str:!oldstring!=%newstring%! echo !str!>>new!filename!is used and prints oldstring=newstring (values) when set str=%str:!oldstring!=%newstring%% echo !str!>>new!filename! is used.

Comment: Wrong question (it's hard balancing two discussions). I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

having spent some time at this I got the correct way:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set oldstring=AF-07295
set /a count=1000

for %%f in (*.*) do (
  set /a count=!count!+1
  for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%%f) do (
    set str=%%i

    call set str=%%str:!oldstring!=!count!%%
    echo !str! >> %%~nf.ordnew

  )
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set filein="c:\program files\test1.txt"
set fileout="c:\program files\test2.txt"
set old=@VERSION@
set new=2.0.3
for /f "tokens=* delims=¶" %%i in ( '"type %filein%"') do (
    set str=%%i
    set str=!str:%old%=%new%!
    echo !str! >> %fileout% 
)
```

working perfect
and isn't removing white spaces at the begining of the lines file