# batch script to check the size of file and send mail if greater

Tags: batch-file

I have been working on a batch script which checks for the size of a file and send an email  in case the size is greater than 0 byte:

```
set V_TMP_FILE="D:\pmserver\Tgtfiles\XLI_stage\f_cdc_flag1.out" 
set minbytesize=0  
if exist %V_TMP_FILE% (
FOR %%A IN ('%V_TMP_FILE%') DO set size=%%~zA
if %size% GTR %minbytesize% (
    %V_EMAIL_PATH%\postie -host:internalmail.usa.xl -to:"%V_TO_EMAIL_ID%" -from:%COMPUTERNAME%@xlgroup.com -s:"%V_SRC_TABLE_NM% %V_SUBJ%" -msg:"%V_MSG%" 
) else (
    echo %V_TMP_FILE% is EMPTY
)
```

---

I am getting the below error -

Standard output and error:

```
h file. 0 was unexpected at this time.

D:\Informatica91\server\bin>if  GTR 0 (
```

---

Kindly help me solve this issue , its really taking me time to dig in the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Batch parses an entire command, even if it's spread across multiple lines, before executing it. As part of that procedure, it substitutes ANY %var% variable for the value `VAR` has at the time it was PARSED - that is, **BEFORE** it is executed.

`SIZE` was **NOT** set before the `IF...` was parsed, so its value is replaced by (nothing) and hence the command is interpreted as `IF (nothing) GTR 0`

Further, the single-quotes around the filename would change the filename dince `'` is a valid filename character.

Number of cures: easiest seems to be

```
if exist %V_TMP_FILE% (
FOR %%A IN (%V_TMP_FILE%) DO (
if %%~zA GTR %minbytesize% (
    %V_EMAIL_PATH%\postie -host:internalmail.usa.xl -to:"%V_TO_EMAIL_ID%" -from:%COMPUTERNAME%@xlgroup.com -s:"%V_SRC_TABLE_NM% %V_SUBJ%" -msg:"%V_MSG%" 
) else (
    echo %V_TMP_FILE% is EMPTY
)
```

Comment: thanks for the help ,i tried using the above, but it stil doesn't work, i am getting no mails even when the file is greater than 0 byte, plesae help .

Comment: earlier i was using this script- for %%A in (%V_TMP_FILE%) do ( if %%~zA==0 ( echo. "%%A" is empty ) else ( %V_EMAIL_PATH%\postie -host:internalmail.usa.xl -to:"%V_TO_EMAIL_ID%" -from:%COMPUTERNAME%@xlgroup.com -s:"%V_SRC_TABLE_NM% %V_SUBJ%" -msg:"%V_MSG%" -a:%V_TMP_FILE% ) ) - it was working in the else part , but not in the true part ie when file size =0;   can you help me with this one .

Comment: I believe you'll find your parentheses are unbalanced. There appears to be 3 open but only 2 close-parentheses in your original post, so I assumed you were only posting a part-statement. Adding the DO added one more. Try temporarily replacing the `%V_EMAIL_PATH...` with a simple `ECHO %V_TMP_FILE% is NOT EMPTY` and possibly complete the list of possibilities by adding `)) else (echo %V_TMP_FILE% is missing)` to the code I posted in my response. the first `)` closes the `DO (` and the second the `IF` on the first line. Test against `V_TMP_FILE` absent, zero-length & non-zero length.

Answer (score 0):

How many times have we had to answer this...

Ok, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291341/a-batch-file-to-read-a-file-and-replace-a-string-with-a-new-one/15291885#15291885) answer that I wrote maybe a week ago. It explains ***everything***...