# Batch Script to check file size & send email

Tags: batch-file

I am new to scripting.
I am looking for a script through which i can get to know a particular file size on a remote machine & send an email to me accordingly on daily basis
Please let me know in step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Batch parses an entire command, even if it's spread across multiple lines, before executing it. As part of that procedure, it substitutes ANY %var% variable for the value VAR has at the time it was PARSED - that is, BEFORE it is executed.

SIZE was NOT set before the IF... was parsed, so its value is replaced by (nothing) and hence the command is interpreted as IF (nothing) GTR 0

Further, the single-quotes around the filename would change the filename dince ' is a valid filename character.

Number of cures: easiest seems to be

```
if exist %V_TMP_FILE% (
FOR %%A IN (%V_TMP_FILE%) DO (
if %%~zA GTR %minbytesize% (
    %V_EMAIL_PATH%\postie -host:internalmail.usa.xl -to:"%V_TO_EMAIL_ID%" -from:%COMPUTERNAME%@xlgroup.com -s:"%V_SRC_TABLE_NM% %V_SUBJ%" -msg:"%V_MSG%" 
) else (
    echo %V_TMP_FILE% is EMPTY
)
```

Comment: Remember if you copy an answer from somewhere else it is polite to reference the source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473303/batch-script-to-check-the-size-of-file-and-send-mail-if-greater Also... make sure it is relevant or at least explain why you think it helps - to me there seems to be a disconnect between the question asked and your response.